# AJAX call after onbeforeunload event is not working, only when refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to handle the `onbeforeunload` event so that when the user closes the browser tab, a message will appear saying something like: `Are you sure you want to leave this page?` (The default browser message it's okay).

I was able to achieve something like this using this code:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    return "";
}
```

But I realized that if I close the tab without refreshing the page beforehand, no message will appear. If I open the page, refresh (I can see a message from the browser) and then I click on close the tab, then I'm getting a message from the browser asking if I'm sure about leaving the page. If I don't refresh first, nothing happens.

I would like to do something like this (pseudo-code):

```
If user refresh the page:
    Nothing happen
If user close the tab/browser:
    Show browser alert message + run ajax call in the background.
```

I tried something like this but also didn't work:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: '/some-view/',
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function () {
      console.log("it works!");
    }
  });
  return "";
}
```

Could someone provide a valid example for 2021? Almost all old stackoverflow questions are no longer supported by modern browsers and the methods are deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that ajax is an async call, and it won't wait for it to return anything. You can try to make your ajax call synchronous:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: '/some-view/',
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false,
    success: function () {
      alert("it works!");
    }
  });
  return "";
}
```

There is no reliable way to distinguish between `reload` and `close`. Page is being unloaded in both cases.

Comment: Then everytime the user clicks a button and that submits a form that is processed in the backend, an alert message will be displayed...which is a nonsense.

It seems that the ajax code is not working either...I don't know what could be wrong.

Comment: if the alert shows up, the ajax code works.... and about the event, that's how it works, you can unbind it if user submits a form

Comment: I'm sorry I meant the default browser alert message (Chrome) not the ajax alert.